# perl concat 5 arrays on same index

Tags: arrays, perl

I have five arrays and I tried to write them into one array for several hours now. Strangely it works for the first three arrays but as soon as I add the fourth the indexes are messed up or something. The length of all arrays is the same so it should not be a problem to do it like this.

```
Examples:

INPUT:
@names = [jeff,george,ringo,chris]
@td = [10/04/2014,11/04/2014,12/04/2014,13/04/2014]
@vct1= [5,6,4,0]
@vct2= [1,1,2,2]
@vct3= [6,0,1,5]

Expected OUTPUT:
@ffo = [jeff 10/04/2014 5 1 6
        george 11/04/2014 6 1 0
        ringo 12/04/2014 4 2 1
        chris 13/04/2014 0 2 5]
```

Here is my code for merging:

```
 for ($i=0;$i<@vct1;++$i) {
     push(@ffo,trim(@names[$i])."\t".trim(@td[$i])."\t".trim(@vct1[$i])."\t".trim(@vct2[$i]).trim(@vct3[$i])."\n");
 }
```

I tried List::MoreUtils with zip and

```
 @ffo = map { $names[$_], $td[$_], $vct1[$_], $vct2[$_], $vct3[$_],  } 0 .. $#names;
```

but it did not work. Does anyone know why?

If I use the arrays like this it works:

```
@names = qw(jeff george ringo chris);
@td = qw(10/04/2014 11/04/2014 12/04/2014 13/04/2014);
@vct1 = qw(5 6 4 0);
@vct2 = qw(1 1 2 2);
@vct3 = qw(6 0 1 5);

for ($i=0;$i<@names;++$i) {
print @names[$i]."\t".@td[$i]."\t".@vct1[$i]."\t".@vct2[$i]."\t".@vct3[$i]."\n";
}

OUTPUT:
jeff    10/04/2014  5   1   6
george  11/04/2014  6   1   0
ringo   12/04/2014  4   2   1
chris   13/04/2014  0   2   5
```

Comment: Probably because you're assigning anonymous arrays to your vars instead of lists.

Comment: That code does not compile, your values are not quoted, and you are assigning array refs `[ ... ]` instead of a list. Post your real code, please. Also, post the code which prints your output, and the exact output you get. Furthermore, there is no function called `trim` in Perl, so you'll need to say which module its from, or show the code for the subroutine.

Comment: Your `map` statement should work, as should `zip`, if you used that. So my guess is it is either your arrays or your output functionality that is the problem. But it is impossible to say anything else about it until you show the relevant code.

Comment: If I declare the arrays like this it works:

 atnames = qw(jeff george ringo chris);
 ...    
     
     
     

for ($i=0;$i<@names;++$i) {
     print @names[$i]."\t".@td[$i]."\t".@vct1[$i]."\t".@vct2[$i]."\t".@vct3[$i]."\n";
}  Output: jeff 10/04/2014 5 1 6
george 11/04/2014 6 1 0
ringo 12/04/2014 4 2 1
chris 13/04/2014 0 2 5

Comment: Use the edit button and add the information to your question, it is hard to read in the comments. And please don't use `...` to examplify, write your *real* code, the code you used. Nothing else.

Comment: Posting code that already works is probably not the best way to ask for help. How are we supposed to be able to tell you what's wrong with your code when there is nothing wrong with it?

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first method should work, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my @names = qw(jeff george ringo chris);
my @td = qw(10/04/2014 11/04/2014 12/04/2014 13/04/2014);
my @vct1= qw(5 6 4 0);
my @vct2= qw(1 1 2 2);
my @vct3= qw(6 0 1 5);

my @ffo;
for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#names; $i++) {
    push @ffo, join("\t", $names[$i], $td[$i], $vct1[$i], $vct2[$i], $vct3[$i]);
}

print Dumper(\@ffo);
```

---

Running:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'jeff 10/04/2014  5   1   6',
          'george   11/04/2014  6   1   0',
          'ringo    12/04/2014  4   2   1',
          'chris    13/04/2014  0   2   5'
        ];
```

Comment: @TLP The asker never show us his real code, and that is the biggest problem in his question. So what I can do is show him the working code, and hope that may be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I'll take a wild stab at answering this, although you have not supplied enough information for me to be sure. This code:

```
@names = [jeff,george,ringo,chris]
@td = [10/04/2014,11/04/2014,12/04/2014,13/04/2014]
@vct1= [5,6,4,0]
@vct2= [1,1,2,2]
@vct3= [6,0,1,5]
```

Does not compile. There are several things wrong with it:

- It lacks semi-colons `;` at the end of the lines,
- The values are not quoted, i.e. `"jeff","george"`, the string `10/04/2014` will be interpreted as three numbers being divided and will become `0.00124...`,
- You are assigning a single value to the arrays: an anonymous array reference `[ ... ]`

My guess is that you really have something like this:

```
@names = ["jeff","george","ringo","chris"];
@td = ["10/04/2014","11/04/2014","12/04/2014","13/04/2014"];
@vct1= [5,6,4,0];
@vct2= [1,1,2,2];
@vct3= [6,0,1,5];
```

And you do not realize that this will create a two-dimensional array, where the first element in each array contains the arrays you want. I.e.: `$names[0][0]` contains `"jeff"`, and so on.

You say that it works when you use `qw()`, which is a function that will create a list of quoted arguments (mnemonic: QuoteWords). These two are equivalent statements:

```
@names = qw(jeff george ringo chris);
@names = ("jeff", "george", "ringo", "chris");
```

So... use either of these ways to assign values to your arrays.

And also, you should always use

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

As they will tell you about all the mistakes you make. I am guessing if you add them to your code now, you will get quite a few warnings and fatal errors. Which is a good thing. Not knowing about what you did wrong does not help improve your code.

Answer (score 1):

In your original code, you had this:

```
@names = [jeff,george,ringo,chris]
@td = [10/04/2014,11/04/2014,12/04/2014,13/04/2014]
@vct1= [5,6,4,0]
@vct2= [1,1,2,2]
@vct3= [6,0,1,5]
```

But you should not declare arrays with the [ ] operator, unless you are interested in an array of anonymous arrays.

Thus, @td, for example, contains only a single element, which is a reference to an anonymous array:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @td = [10/04/2014,11/04/2014,12/04/2014,13/04/2014];
foreach my $element (@td) {
        print "$element\n"; # Prints a single element ARRAY(0x7f8e108070d0)
}

print "Size of \@td: ", scalar(@td), "\n"; # Prints 1
```

You avoid this problem when you use the `qw` operator which knows to return an array, not an array reference, containing the elements you want.